# Answer create view is not storing data in the database in django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I am working on a Hybrid of Quora and StackOverflow clone. I have made an "add_answer" view for letting me add answers to the questions but for some reasons it is showing the integrity error:
[Here's the error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WNW0.jpg)
But when I add through admin panel then it adds answer in the database. What is wrong? 
The code is as follows:

1. models.py:

```
    class Answer(models.Model):  
        content = models.TextField()  
        user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)  
        question = models.ForeignKey(Question,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=False)  
        created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)  
        upvotes = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)  
        is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)  

        def __str__(self):  
            return '{}\'s Answer'.format(self.user.username)  

        class Meta:  
                ordering = ('-upvotes','-created')
```

2. forms.py:

```
    class AnswerForm(forms.ModelForm):
        content = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea,help_text='Your Answer in Detail. Note: MarkDown is enabled.')

        class Meta:
            model = Answer
            fields = ['content']

        def __init__(self,author,question,*args,**kwargs):
            super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)
            self.user = author
            self.question = question
```

3. "add_answer" view (views.py):

```
@login_required
def add_answer(request, pk):
    ques = get_object_or_404(Question, pk = pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AnswerForm(request.user,ques,request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            answer = form.save(commit=False)
            answer.content = cd['content']
            answer.save()
            messages.success(request,'Success! Your Answer has been added!')
            return redirect('forum')
        else:
            messages.error(request,form.errors)
    else:
        form = AnswerForm(request.user,ques)
    return render(request,'discussion/answer_create.html',{'form':form})
```

4. answer_create.html (template):

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load markdownify %}
{% block title %} Add Answer {% endblock %}

{% block header %}    
    <h2 class="display-5" style="font-family: x-locale-heading-primary,zillaslab,Palatino,Palatino Linotype,x-locale-heading-secondary,serif;">
        Add Answer:
    </h2>  
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    {% if form.errors %}
    <h4 class="alert alert-primary alert-warning" role="alert">Errors:<br> {{form.errors}}  <hr></h4>
    {% endif %}
    <form action="" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form.as_p}}
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

It would be really grateful if somebody helps me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to assign the question instance to answer model

> answer.question = ques

```
ques = get_object_or_404(Question, pk = pk)
if form.is_valid():
   cd = form.cleaned_data
   answer = form.save(commit=False)
   answer.question = ques
   answer.content = cd['content']
   answer.save()
```

you can also do the following in model form init

```
def __init__(self,author,question,*args,**kwargs):
   super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)
   self.form.instance.user = author
   self.form.instance.question = question
```

Comment: Thanks your solution is working. But can I know the reason why it was not working before because previously, I what I did was I passed question and the user at the time of initialization of form only (_like: AnswerForm(request.user,ques,request.POST)_ ) then why was it not working before?

Comment: In the Form, You used `self.user = author` which set user to form instance, not the actual model, so it should be self.form.instance.user = author.,